# Is this case possible for Decision Tree?

Tags: machine-learning, cart, decision-theory, gini

I am studying decision tree and I would like to know if this case is possible:

We have 2 features, each does not decrease the Gini of the previous node (=> not choose), but their combination (two decisions one after another) decrease the Gini over the previous one (=> loose information)

Possible or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. XOR problem is a simple example for this case. The dataset is $$C_1=(0,1),(1,0), C_2=(1,1),(0,0)$$
where $C_i$ is class $i$. In the root, the class distribution is $1/2-1/2$. Any split (e.g. $x\lessgtr 0.5$, $y\lessgtr0.5$, ...) will result in the same class distribution, so information gain is 0 or gini-index will not decrease. But, the in next step, we'll perfectly classify the samples.

So, a decision tree implementation with *strict* improvement condition on one level won't be able to learn this dataset.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So we can conclude:

"The CART algorithm [...] does not check whether or not the split will lead to the lowest possible impurity several levels down. 
[...] often produces a solution that’s reasonably good but not guaranteed to be optimal."  _Keras, and TensorFlow by Aurelien Geron_

Comment: Yes, of course. Finding the optimal decision tree is np-complete, and the current algorithms follow the greedy approach. See the following: https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/HyafilRivest-ConstructingOptimalBinaryDecisionTreesIsNPComplete.pdf